# how to pass a javascript associative array in ajax to php file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How can i pass data (associative array) to php file.

```
 function ajax(url,data,callback)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if ( xmlhttp.readyState === 4 ) {
                        callback( xmlhttp.responseText );
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(data);
        }
```

Comment: Use [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: json_encode and [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) are your friends

Comment: And please use jQuery, this code looks like the stoneage...

Comment: [Not enough jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 8):

The way i read this, you are in javascript, and you have a javascript object (javascript does not have associative arrays, just arrays and objects). So, whatever data you have, you need to turn it into a string and sent it via POST or GET to your php script. I would recommend including [JSON3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/) as a polyfill to ensure you will have `JSON.stringify` on your page (for cross-browserness). Code will be something like this:

```
var data = {
    someData: 'data',
    moreData: [
        'blah',
        'bleh'
    ]
};

var stringData = JSON.stringify( data );

// using jquery ajax for brevity (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your-php-script.php",
  data: { data: stringData }
});
```

Now your php script can snag that string and turn it back into json itself:

```
<?php
    $dataString = $_POST['data'];
    $data = json_decode($dataString);
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [JSON functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php) to achieve this. It will encode/decode arrays into a notation that javascript can handle.

Comment: No, but it's the only **sane** way.

Comment: you could use serialize() and unserialize(), but you'll probably run into errors somewhere.  JSON was created to do what you want.

Comment: so its like this var json = { 'info' : data};